# Programmatically updating stock in and out Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, simple-product, stock-status

I have a magento 1 store and also a third party, centrally controlled stock system.
Now, I have a script that imports stock from this third party and updates the stock in the magento database which works perfectly.

The code snippet below looks for products which now has a value greater than the out of stock threshold, which in this case is zero, alters the stock status to "in-stock" and saves the collection.
Also in this code snippet is the action to find products which are equal to or less than zero.  This then sets this product to "out-of-stock" and again, saves the collection.
Straight after this, I then grab the index id for the stock status and then I re-index it so that the changes reflect in the front end of the store.

HOWEVER, and this is the issue.  How to I eliminate configurable products from this equation?  I don't want configurable products to be marked as "out-of-stock" as a configurable product always has a stock value of zero????

Can anyone help?  Here's my code so far....

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
// If stock level is more than zero, set to in-stock and save
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('cataloginventory/stock_item_collection');
$outQty = Mage::getStoreConfig('cataloginventory/item/options_min_qty');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('qty', array('gt' => $outQty));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 0);

foreach($collection as $item) {
    $item->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
}
$collection->save();

// If stock level equals zero, set to out-of-stock and save BUT EXCLUDE CONFIGURABLE PRODUCTS
$collectionOut = Mage::getResourceModel('cataloginventory/stock_item_collection');
$collectionOut->addFieldToFilter('qty', array('lteq' => 0));
$collectionOut->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 1);
foreach($collectionOut as $item) {
      $item->setData('is_in_stock', 0);
}
$collectionOut->save();

//Get Stock Status Index Process ID and reindex to display results on front end
$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load(8);
$process->reindexAll();
```

Comment: Think I've found the solution by adding;

->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))